# Compute a matrix comparison of lists with eVenn in R

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I've got a number of lists with pairs of columns of intersecting elements, here supposing sets 1, 2, 3, that can have a 1-to-1, 1-to-many and many-to-many relationship:

```
df1 = data.frame(
    X1 = paste('set100',sample(10,8,replace=TRUE),sep=''),
    X2 = paste('set200',sample(10,8,replace=TRUE),sep='')
)

df2 = data.frame(
    X1 = paste('set100',sample(10,8,replace=TRUE),sep=''),
    X3 = paste('set300',sample(10,8,replace=TRUE),sep='')
)

df3 = data.frame(
    X2 = paste('set100',sample(10,8,replace=TRUE),sep=''),
    X3 = paste('set300',sample(10,8,replace=TRUE),sep='')
)
```

And I want to create a merged matrix of the two-column lists to use them as input for eVenn. In eVenn's 4-way example, the lists are already in an object like this:

```
> head(res3)
         liste_1_.194. liste_2_.149. liste_3_.366. Total_lists   ratios
10345445             1             0             0           1 2.159987
10345762             1             1             0           2 2.223848
10345791             1             1             1           3 2.519503
10345824             0             0             0           0       NA
10346191             0             0             0           0       NA
10346843             0             0             0           0       NA
           ratios    ratios
10345445       NA        NA
10345762 2.085687  2.264225
10345791 2.518024  2.668271
10345824       NA 36.246703
10346191       NA  2.527424
10346843       NA  3.852753
```

I want to be able to call the eVenn command on the merged data like this:

```
mergedmatrix <- create_the_merged_matrix_somehow(df1,df2,df3)
evenn(path_lists="test",res=mergedmatrix,ud=TRUE)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give us a [reproducible example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: thanks, I've edited it a bit now, hopefully it's better.

Comment: @avilella, I have never heard of eVenn, but it seems like what you want to do could be expressed in such a way that knowledge of eVenn is not needed. How is the res3 data formed? Is it a frequency table of some sort? What are the ratios? When you say, "merged matrix" I'm thinking you mean some type of join, or `merge()` but the values in your df1-df3 data frames look like the column headings for res3. Can you clarify?

Comment: @JD Long: FYI `eVenn` is a package, and `res3` is one of its example data sets. A quick look at `eVenn` suggests that it is quite an eclectic package - lots of effort put into places it was not needed, and some of big holes in other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your example is difficult to follow. I would suggest that you avoid using the `eVenn` package. The package documentation is very limited, and the examples are very cryptic. It does not produce a figure in the standard X11 (on unix systems) display, and will only print the results to file.

I would suggest you consider the `limma` package, [available](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) from [Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org). It has functionality to make nice Venn diagrams. You can see some examples [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/venn.htm).

I guess that what you call `create_the_merged_matrix_somehow()` would be solved by `vennCounts()` in `limma`.

Comment: thanks nullglob, I ended up using vennCounts and vennDiagram in limma. It took me a bit to figure out the merges for my lists, but all fine after that.